# What event fires when an AJAX request is sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What handler should I use to catch the moment when an AJAX request has just been sent to the server within `document.ready`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the `onreadystatechange` callback?

Comment: That change a lot in jQuery 1.5, what version do you have?

Comment: i mean the moment when last packet of request was sent out of http -toward network interface.

Comment: i have 1.4.2 how it look like in 1.5?

Comment: In jquery 1.5 a deferred object was added and ajax function was practically rewritten, check this link for more information on how to use it http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/ , if possible, i recommend updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete).

```
$('#el').ajaxComplete(function() {
    …
});
```

---

### Edit

Try this:

```
$(window).ajaxComplete(function() {
    …
});
```

**Note:** these only work if the AJAX request was sent with jQuery.

Comment: but i dont't need to attach to an element. i just need a function that listens if request is gone to server and if it - close that interface for 30 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for `.ajaxSend()` or `.ajaxStart()`  [Jquery AJAX events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)